# TRIM Support in PERC H310 Mini

Tags: ssd, dell-perc, trim

I am running Debian 8 on a Dell PowerEdge R420.

The OS is installed onto a INTEL SSDSC2BA800G3T SSD running the 5DV1DL03 firmware.

The SSD is connected through a PERC - H310 RAID controller (fw 2.121.14-3811). There is no RAID configured, the SSD is a standalone drive.

The root partition is EXT4 and, after I've configured fstab to have it running with noatime and discard, I've tried running fstrim -v / on the root partition, but only got the following message:

```
# fstrim -v /
fstrim: /: the discard operation is not supported
```

The SSD does support trim, so I am wondering if the issue isn't with the RAID controller:

```
# hdparm -I /dev/sda | grep TRIM
       *    Data Set Management TRIM supported (limit 6 blocks)
       *    Deterministic read ZEROs after TRIM
```

Is there any way I could go around this and have TRIM enabled on this SSD?

Comment: I imagine if you use a SUPPORTED ssd then yeah, not so much if you carry on with a hack like this.

Comment: If you would have at least put the effort into figuring out what drive it is, you would have noticed that it actually is a Dell drive. But thanks for the downvote, that was helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, for anyone looking for an answer on this or a similar question, it looks like this controller is not passing through the TRIM commands to the SSD. However it seems that some of the newer ones do actually pass those through: http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/servers/f/906/p/19662382/20849172#20849172